# How to use Vim 7.4 on Mac OS after install it by brew?

Tags: macos, vim

I have installed vim by brew on the newest Mac OS:

```
brew install vim
```

And when I type `brew info vim`, it shows:

```
vim: stable 7.4.891, HEAD
Vi "workalike" with many additional features
http://www.vim.org/
Conflicts with: ex-vi
/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.891 (1612 files, 28M) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/vim.rb
...
```

But if type `vim`, it shows me a `7.3` version's vim:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved
  version 7.3
...
```

How can I use the `7.4` version?

Comment: you have to set the path to vim 7.4 before the 7.3 version in your PATH environment variable

Comment: Thank you. Where to set it? The `~/.zshrc` file or `~/.bashrc` file? I didn't find that.

Comment: Your path is set in different files depending on your shell. For bash, look at `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`. For zsh, look at .`zshenv` or `.zshrc`. For either, also look in `.profile`.

Answer (score 17):

Just need exit the terminal and re-enter, brew will install vim link at /usr/local/bin/vim, but it will be enable only when terminal started.

Comment: I did just that and even restarted my computer, but when I use :version in Vim I still get "VIM - Vi Improved 7.3". Yet, when I execute "brew install vim" in the terminal I get "Warning: vim-7.4.1952 already installed".

Strange.

Comment: @Sean what's the result of `echo $PATH` and `which vim`? should be `/usr/local/bin` first in your path and `/usr/local/bin/vim`

Comment: Try `brew link vim --overwrite` if really sure, maybe 3rd party install vim block you.

Answer (score 7):

You need to set PATH so that `/usr/local/bin` appears before `/usr/bin`

vim .zshrc(if you use zsh) or .bash_profile and paste

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

hope this help you!

Answer (score 3):

My solution is put these into my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
alias vi='/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim'
alias vim='/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim'
alias gvi='/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim -g'
```

I installed MacVim.

So it works well.

## Reference

> https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/2ukp5j/starting_homebrew_version_of_vim/